# How to replace different matching groups with different text in Regex

Tags: regex, replace, regex-group

I have the following text:

```
dangernounC2
cautionnounC2
alertverbC1
dangerousadjectiveB1
```

What I need as an output is:

```
danger (n)
caution (n)
alert (v)
dangerous (adj)
```

I would know how to do this if the list was, for example, all nouns or all verbs etc., but is there a way to replace each matching group with different corresponding text?

Comment: What language are you using for your regex processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regular expression that would work for you. But it's a kind of trick that only works because this substitution is part of the match.

**Regular expression**

```
(n)ounC2|(v)erbC1|(adj)ectiveB1
```

**Substitution**

```
 ($1$2$3)
```

> Use `(\1\2\3)` instead if you're using Python

**Explanation**

`(n)ounC2|(v)erbC1|(adj)ectiveB1` will match either `nounC2`, `verbC1` or `adjectiveB1`

When it matches `nounC2`, Group 1 will contain `n`, Group 2 and 3 contain nothing
When it matches `verbC1`, Group 2 will contain `v`, Group 1 and 3 contain nothing
When it matches `adjectiveB1`, Group 3 will contain `adj`, Group 1 and 2 contain nothing

Every match is replaced with a space followed by the values of the 3 groups between parenthesis.

**Demos**

[Demo on RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/QzLfGu/1/)

Code snippet (JavaScript)

```js
const regex = /(n)ounC2|(v)erbC1|(adj)ectiveB1/gm;
const str = `
dangernounC2
cautionnounC2
alertverbC1
dangerousadjectiveB1
eatverbC1
prettyadjectiveB1`;
const subst = ` ($1$2$3)`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: @BorisAdasson did it answered your question ?